# Node.JS POST request to Express app secured by passport

Tags: node.js, http, express, request, passport.js

**Mechanism :**

I am making this POST request to my API :

```
request.post('http://localhost:9876/api/alerts',{body: "test"}, function (err, res, body) {
        if (err) {
            self.emit('log','ERROR : API error - '+err);
        }
        self.emit('log','RESPONSE - '+res.statusCode);
    });
```

On the server side, I have :

```
app.post('/api/alerts',function(req,res){
    console.log(req);
    res.status(200).send('OK');
});
```

Communication is made and it returns a 200 status. But on the server side, I see no trace of my request's body.

The full 'req' log is available here : https://gist.github.com/xShirase/0f9de0048e5cfa40a98c , the most relevant part being :

```
body: {},
```

I was wondering if it was coming from the Passport middleware that I use to secure the rest of my routes, or if I just botched the client request...

I have tried many different requests formats on the client side, and nothing has worked, and I have very little experience with Passport, so please let me know where my problem comes from.

Comment: Are you just having trouble with getting POST data at all? I.E. if you take out the passport middleware does it work?

Comment: Good question. I removed the Passport middleware and the same thing is going on... Strangely, all the other routes of my API (requested through a webpage) work nicely, POST included. only this one where I need to POST programatically fails...

Comment: I solved the problem by not using the request.post and constructing my request object like I usually do. Still not telling me what is wrong with my request.post()...

Comment: Perhaps try POSTing the data via a tool like Postman (Chrome extension) and verifying that there is, indeed, POST data going to your server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you have a (custom) middleware earlier up in the route/middleware chain that is doing something like:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var buffer = '';
  req.setEncoding('utf8');
  req.on('data', function(d) {
    buffer += d;
  }).on('end', function() {
    req.body = buffer;
    next();
  });
});
```

then you probably shouldn't expect `req.body` to be populated since the common body parsing modules expect a `Content-Type` of one of `application/json`, `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, or `multipart/form-data`. Your `request()` doesn't seem to be setting any of these, which really is correct since it's just free-form data, but that means no middleware is reading request data.

Comment: Yes, once I've set the headers, then used a regular request(), it worked. I had the idea that request.post() was setting these up automatically... I guess I was wrong :)